# Are questions about the availability of information on topic?

Tags: discussion

In my career I have had and have been asked a lot of questions regarding the existence, location, accessibility, etc of certain information. For example, "Where can I find information in English about Russian weather satellites?" or "Does anyone know of a comprehensive list of named storms for the 20th century?"

Answer (score 3):

This could lead to short link only answers, which may have limited lifetime.

Nevertheless I tend to say yes, as such questions could be helpful to exchange valuable knowledge in the community. They should be of interest for other users as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'm in favour of allowing iff as a community we agree that answers to this type of question should include not just direct links to the requested information, but also a brief explanation of how the answerer got to it - e.g. "the BGS has done some work in this area, so following references from their current projects page..." or whatever. That way the answer serves the two-fold purpose of (1) immediate information, (2) teaching research skills, and (3) allowing future readers to potentially navigate around bitrot.